# SQL update in JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I'm having trouble updating a JSON object, which is represented as an object rather than an array. I need to dynamically bypass all the keys, but they have a random number in their name, which can be absolutely anything (there is no way to change the JSON view) and get to the visibility to change its value. For example:
Set the visibility to false for all bicycle keys

```
{
"objects": {
  "object1": {
     "components": {
        "car": { "visibility": true},
        "bicycle": { "visibility": true},
        "bicycle1": { "visibility": true},
        "bicycle2": { "visibility": true},
        "van": { "visibility": true}
      }
  },
  "object2": {
     "components": {
        "car": { "visibility": true},
        "bicycle5": { "visibility": true},
        "van": { "visibility": true}
      }
  }
},
  "objectN": {
     "components": {
        "car": { "visibility": true},
        "bicycle": { "visibility": true},
        "bicycle3": { "visibility": true},
        "van": { "visibility": true}
      }
  }
}
}
```

Result JSON

```
{
"objects": {
  "object1": {
     "components": {
        "car": { "visibility": true},
        "bicycle": { "visibility": false},
        "bicycle1": { "visibility": false},
        "bicycle2": { "visibility": false},
        "van": { "visibility": true}
      }
  },
  "object2": {
     "components": {
        "bicycle5": { "visibility": false},
        "van": { "visibility": true}
      }
  }
},
  "objectN": {
     "components": {
        "car": { "visibility": true},
        "bicycle": { "visibility": false},
        "bicycle3": { "visibility": false},
        "van": { "visibility": true}
      }
  }
}
}
```

I have attempted to use `JSON_MODIFY` and `OPEN_JSON`, but as I am new to SQL, I am having trouble. I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: Please let us what what flavour of SQL, MySQL, T-SQL, SQL-Server, SQLLite etc. by adding your RDBMS as a tag

Comment: Please, read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms and [ask] first.

Comment: In SQL Server, as lame as it may sound, a plain `REPLACE('"visibility": true', '"visibility": false')` is the least aggravating way, as the JSON methods are *not* suited to varying schemas like this. It *can* be done with sufficient cleverness, you just don't want to.

Comment: @JeroenMostert,Thank you for your answer, but I can't just replace it since the number of objectN and componentN is not known and it can be absolutely any number.

Comment: I'm not sure why that invalidates @JeroenMostert 's suggestion. `REPLACE('"visibility": true', '"visibility": false')` doesn't reference `objectN` at all.

Comment: I interpreted your question as needing to change the value *everywhere*, *unconditionally*. If you need something more specific you should extend your question with an example of before, input, and after.

Comment: Side note, the JSON you've provided isn't valid either. You're missing a double quote (`"`) at `objects`, and you have an extra brace (`}`) at the end.

Comment: @Larnu, And how do I make a replace if I need to hit every path where the key has a random number?

Comment: `REPLACE` already does that, @Boni . `SELECT REPLACE('aaaaaa','a','b')` would return `'bbbbbb'` not `'baaaaa'`. `REPLACE` *replaces* *every* instance of a pattern, *not* the first instance.

Comment: @Larnu, So my problem is not to replace, but to bypass all nested keys that have a random number in their name. Your suggested REPLACE won't help me

Comment: So your statement *" I need to update the "visibility" value to "false" for every "object" and every "component" where their numbers in the name may change and can be any."* Is incorrect; you need to [edit] your question to explain the *actual* problem. If you need to "bypass nested keys" you **don't** want to update *"**every** "object" and **every** "component""*. In your question, I would assume this means that *none* of those values should be updated, so what values *should* be..?

Comment: @Larnu, Thank you, I will try to restate the problem

Comment: You [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75147856/revisions) doesn't really explain anything. YOu haven't clarified which values need updating, and which don't. For the JSON you've provided, show what the expected JSON you want is, and why some where changed to `False` while others were not.